# Android - Stripe - Applying style to PaymentMethodsActivity

Tags: android, stripe-payments, android-theme

I'm currently implementing [Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) into my application.

And using the [example code from their documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/customer-information), I'm starting their `PaymentMethodsActivity` like this.

```
private fun startPaymentSelectActivity() {
    val intent = PaymentMethodsActivity.newIntent(this@PaymentActivity)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_SOURCE)
}
```

However, the created `PaymentMethodsActivity`'s theme does not follow my app's theme, it's using their blue `Toolbar`. Like this

[image: PaymentMethodsActivity with Blue Toolbar]

How do I apply a Theme to this Activity?

Answer (score 1):

[ScreenShot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Pjp.png)

1.Download Stripe from here

"https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android"

2.import stripe module in your project and Update UI as you want from it's res folder

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this into your styles.xml and customize the colors

```
<style name="StripeDefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#0091ea</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color_default</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/control_normal_color_default</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
    </style>
```

Be careful to keep the style name ( **name="StripeDefaultTheme"** )

I'm using **'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'** and that's work fine.

Source: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/414